# Filtered colimit of a topological space

Tags: gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits

Suppose that $X$ is a space filtered by closed subspaces $X_{1}\subset X_{2}\subset \dots$.

As topological space $X=\operatorname{colim}_{n}X_{n}$.
We define $Y_{n}=X_{n+1}/X_{n}$, and consider the induced maps $Y_{n}\rightarrow Y_{n+1}$. Let define $Y=\operatorname{colim}_{n}Y_{n}$.

*Question:* $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

Comment: What does the quotient notation $X_{n + 1}/X_n$ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not true in general.

Consider simply $X_n=X$. In this case $Y_n$ (and consequently $Y$) will be a singleton.

Comment: You are right! My question question is stupid.